# Second-Order Taylor Series Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

30 characters needed to edit this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### To the newly added part c)

Your ODE system is linear, thus also the relation of boundary values is linear. As in both runs the initial value of $y$ is $y(0)=1$, any linear continuation of these initial values will preserve that constant and only change $x(0)$. Now we have the values
\begin{array}{l|l}x(0)&x(0.5)\\ \hline
0.5&1.49089\\
1.0&2.32867
\end{array}
we need to find a value $s$ so that $(1-s)\,1.49089+s\,2.32867=2$ and then use $x(0)=(1-s)\,0.5+s\,1.0$ as the appropriate initial value.

Or in other terms, the empirical linear relation is 
$$
x(0.5)=0.65311+ 1.67556\,x(0)
$$
which can be solved for $x(0.5)=2$.

---

The Python script

```
def integrate(x0,y0):
    t,x,y,h = 0.0,x0,y0,0.1
    print "\\begin{array}{l|l|ll|ll}k&t_k&x_k&p_k&y_k&q_k\\\\\\hline"
    for k in range(6):
        p,q = h*(x+y)+0.5*h**2*((t+1)*x+y),h*t*x+0.5*h**2*((t+1)*x+t*y)
        print "%2d & %.2f & %.8f & %.8f & %.8f & %.8f \\\\"%(k,t,x,p,y,q)
        x0,y0,x,y,t = x,y,x+p, y+q, t+h
    print "\\end{array}"
    return x0,y0

a=0.5; fa,ga =  integrate(a,1.)
b=1.0; fb,gb =  integrate(b,1.)
c = b - (fb-2)*(b-a)/(fb-fa); fc,gc = integrate(c,1.)
```

produces the tables for step size $h=0.1$ where the last satisfies both boundary conditions.

\begin{array}{l|l|ll|ll}k&t_k&x_k&p_k&y_k&q_k\\\hline
 0 & 0.00 & 0.50000000 & 0.15750000 & 1.00000000 & 0.00250000 \\
 1 & 0.10 & 0.65750000 & 0.17462875 & 1.00250000 & 0.01069250 \\
 2 & 0.20 & 0.83212875 & 0.19459086 & 1.01319250 & 0.02264854 \\
 3 & 0.30 & 1.02671961 & 0.21810895 & 1.03584104 & 0.03902903 \\
 4 & 0.40 & 1.24482856 & 0.24605801 & 1.07487007 & 0.06065668 \\
 5 & 0.50 & 1.49088657 & 0.27950062 & 1.13552675 & 0.08856479 \\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{l|l|ll|ll}k&t_k&x_k&p_k&y_k&q_k\\\hline
 0 & 0.00 & 1.00000000 & 0.21000000 & 1.00000000 & 0.00500000 \\
 1 & 0.10 & 1.21000000 & 0.23318000 & 1.00500000 & 0.01925750 \\
 2 & 0.20 & 1.44318000 & 0.26052412 & 1.02425750 & 0.03854694 \\
 3 & 0.30 & 1.70370412 & 0.29303895 & 1.06280444 & 0.06377941 \\
 4 & 0.40 & 1.99674307 & 0.33194281 & 1.12658384 & 0.09610009 \\
 5 & 0.50 & 2.32868588 & 0.37871555 & 1.22268394 & 0.13695615 \\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{l|l|ll|ll}k&t_k&x_k&p_k&y_k&q_k\\\hline
 0 & 0.00 & 0.80383973 & 0.18940317 & 1.00000000 & 0.00401920 \\
 1 & 0.10 & 0.99324290 & 0.21020914 & 1.00401920 & 0.01589727 \\
 2 & 0.20 & 1.20345204 & 0.23465715 & 1.01991647 & 0.03230967 \\
 3 & 0.30 & 1.43810919 & 0.26364237 & 1.05222614 & 0.05406932 \\
 4 & 0.40 & 1.70175156 & 0.29824844 & 1.10629547 & 0.08219491 \\
 5 & 0.50 & 2.00000000 & 0.33979149 & 1.18849038 & 0.11797123 \\
\end{array}

Comment: This solution can only be as good as the integration method, with a smaller integration step you will need to correct $x(0)$ a little.

Answer (score 2):

First off, we take the second derivatives:
$$\begin{align}\ddot x&=\dot x+\dot y=x+y+tx=(t+1)x+y\\
\ddot y&= x+t\dot x=x+t(x+y)=(t+1)x+ty\end{align}$$
To go from one time step to the next we just do
$$\begin{align}t_{k+1}&=t+k+\Delta t\\
x_{k+1}&=x_k+\Delta t\dot x_k+\frac12(\Delta t)^2\ddot x_k=x_k+\Delta t(x_k+y_k)+\frac12(\Delta t)^2((t_k+1)x_k+y_k)\\
y_{k+1}&=y_k+\Delta t\dot y_k+\frac12(\Delta t)^2\ddot y_k=x_k+\Delta t\,t_ky_k+\frac12(\Delta t)^2((t_k+1)x_k+t_ky_k)\end{align}$$
Assuming an initial value problem we just set initial values $t_0$, $x_0$, and $y_0$, choose a step size $\Delta t$ and integrate. In the following Matlab code, $t_0=0$, $x_0=1$, $y_0=0$ and we integrate from $t_0$ to $t_f=2$, choosing a suitable step size. The Matlab `ODE45` solution is also plotted for comparison.

```
% taylor2.m

clear all;
close all;

f = @(t,y) [1 1;t 0]*y;

t0 = 0;
tf = 2;
x0 = 1;
y0 = 0;
[tau,eta] = ode45(f,[t0 tf],[x0 y0]);

npts = 30;
t = zeros(npts+1);
x = zeros(npts+1);
y = zeros(npts+1);
Dt = (tf-t0)/npts;
t(1) = t0;
x(1) = x0;
y(1) = y0;
for k = 1:npts,
    t(k+1) = t(k)+Dt;
    x(k+1) = x(k)+Dt*(x(k)+y(k))+1/2*Dt^2*((t(k)+1)*x(k)+y(k));
    y(k+1) = y(k)+Dt*t(k)*x(k)+1/2*Dt^2*((t(k)+1)*x(k)+t(k)*y(k));
end

plot(eta(:,1),eta(:,2),'k-',x,y,'r--');
title(['Solution for \Deltat = ' num2str(Dt)]);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
legend('ODE45','Taylor','Location','best');
```

[image: Plot of solution to differential equation]

As can be seen at this step size, the accuracy seems OK, at least in comparison with the `ODE45` results.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, and I think you are doing the right thing. When I tried a step size of $0.2$ the solution was visibly inaccurate. It's good to have a reliable solution to compare with so you know you aren't just computing garbage. How does your solution look at $\Delta t=0.1$?

Comment: Here is what it looks like for me at your step size. $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline k&t_k&X_k&p_k&Y_k&q_k\\\hline
1&0.000000&1.000000&0.210000&1.000000&0.005000\\\hline
2&0.100000&1.210000&0.233180&1.005000&0.019258\\\hline
3&0.200000&1.443180&0.260524&1.024257&0.038547\\\hline
4&0.300000&1.703704&0.293039&1.062804&0.063779\\\hline
5&0.400000&1.996743&0.331943&1.126584&0.096100\\\hline
6&0.500000&2.328686&0.378716&1.222684&0.136956\\\hline
\end{array}$$ I strongly encourage you to change your image of your table to Mathjax.

Comment: You simply have to at least take the effort to type your problem in using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Copying an image of the problem and pasting a link in your question is just trying to get others to do your homework. So type it in with Mathjax and try to do the problem yourself and show us what partial results you have obtained.